# What can i do with a USB that can run linux?

Tags: boot, usb

I created a bootable Ubuntu USB stick by following this
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview

Now, what can i do with this stick? Can i use it for general storage as well as the bootable of the OS? Can i store the cookies of my browsing session to the stick so that i can continue browsing on whatever device i am on currently?

I do not want to damage the USB stick i am using currently but I think i will try to do the above things.

Comment: The default way you write an ISO to a thumb-drive, has the media written as a RO (read-only) image, meaning you cannot save or change anything on it (convention calls it a CD even though we don't use CDs anymore).  It loads from the 'cd' into RAM, and changes/anything-you-do is stored only in RAM, so when you reboot, or turn the box off (ie. your trial of the system is over), nothing is altered and on next boot it's a new system again. This has advantages.  You can also write the ISO with persistence (which allows saves, changes within limits), or write it so it doesn't use the whole device.

Comment: USB devices risk damage every time they are written to, which means writing the ISO itself to the media has risked any damage that can occur (just like writing anything to a usb-thumb-drive can destroy it; a small risk maybe, but there is risk there).  Booting & using it will only read the usb-drive, all writes are to memory only, so no damage will occur however you use it, since it's only the write that risks destroying part of the device.  When you boot it, you'll notice if you look, the *file-system* you're using is all in RAM, you only have READ access to the thumb-drive...

Comment: Rufus extracts the Ubuntu ISO to FAT32 or NTFS. You can use the excess space on the partition for Linux or Windows Data, (or if FAT32 Mac data). The link you posted is old, nowadays Rufus will create a Linux ext casper-rw Persistence partition so you can save from session to session. Only Linux can save to that ext partition or read from it. Do not use up all the remaining space for it.